# App development in laravel compared to codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel, web-applications, laravel-5

I am new to laravel development and confused how and where to start. I have been working on codeigniter all this while and have developed pretty huge web apps on it. Starting with laravel making a todo application or a single page site is fine but how about building a pretty good web application? How do I start my development?

Like in codeigniter I started writing all my core libraries required for my web application, all the API external calls resided in my libraries and had created set of models in the models folder of the application. There were helpers folder which allowed me to create set of helper functions which I needed before development. Coming to laravel Im confused how to start with. There is no library folder to create libraries or helper functions.There are mostly controllers and the model files remain outside and not arranged in a folder. May be my lack of experience in software development raised this question. Can someone help me on getting started up with laravel development?

1. Where do all the external api calls resides?
2. Is it in a controller or is there a way libraries can be build?
3. Is base controller called a library in laravel?
4. Where can I build my app logics in? Is it inside the controller?
5. Laravel doc says controller just routes the http requests and does the validation.Do I have to put all my business logic inside the model files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all compare between two framework is entirely different especially Laravel and Codeigniter , both have lot of differences in framework core.

Laravel & Phalcon have more able to compare, ok dealing with your questions. You can build more complicated web apps using Laravel much efficient way compare to Codeigniter.

Everything in Laravel is Out-of-Box means feel free to put the things any where only thing is you need to put the proper namespace.

Here i will explain what I'm doing for complex projects. We are dealing with shopping cart Application with Laravel.

1) We are using [Package Development](http://www.walkswithme.net/laravel-5-package-development) concept of Laravel.

2) We build a Core Package to manage every basic things Like CRUD , emails, Cron , Menus etc. (this can be used in multiple projects too)
The structure of the core package is something like below, Its MVC based.

```
Core

   -- Console (some artisan commands of Laravel)

   -- Controllers (handling methods and invoke models )
   -- Modles (Your model files)

   -- Data (some data handling functions means helper functions for your frameworks)

   -- Forms (All the form fields)

   -- Libraries (Put your libraries here)

   -- Tables (Deal with your tables, not DB table structure read laravel doc)
   -- Database

        -- Migrations (your table structure)

        -- Seeds (your tables default values)
```

using this way you're free to write your code in you're own folder structure, you can check the Package repo of [Laravel](http://packalyst.com/),

*Note: You may not understand the most of the terms I explained bcoz of you're noob in this , but its quite simple to start use the Official Docs it will clear every single doubts you have.*

hope it make sense ..

Comment: Thanks for your reply man. Got a macro level idea will checkout the docs as well .